# import libgdx project from github in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, libgdx

I tried to share a libgdx project via github with a friend. but when i import the project with import "projects from Git" the "gradle dependencies" are lost and eclipse doesn`t recognize the source folders anymore. i already tried the following:

deleting the project from the explorer and then import it again with "gradle" - no success

right-click the source folder: build path -> use as source folder    -   no success

replacing the local git-repository with the original project(working project, with all the libraries)  -  no success

iam desperate. i hope someone of you knows a solution for my problem. thanks in advance

Comment: I'd recommend not using Eclipse Mars. I personally use Eclipse Kepler which I've had no issues with. Eclipse Mars seems to have issues with the gradle file and dependencies. It wouldn't update the dependencies when I changed the gradle file. No problems with Kepler.

Comment: I with I could downvote your comment @Barodapride :'(

Comment: How about you just download the project to desktop, unzip it and `import gradle project`? I know this is not really desireable since you cannot use eclipse for your source control directly but at least it's a work around that should work.